Why isn't the generation of new extremal points a problem when transforming to slack form?
We say that a linear program is in slack form if it has the form
Minimize $c^T\cdot x$
such that $Ax=b \land x\ge 0$
, where $A\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}, b\in{\mathbb{R}_{\geq0}}^m, c\in\mathbb{R}^n$ are given and $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$ is a vector of variables.
Any linear program can be transformed to slack form.
If the solution space of a linear program was initially an affine subspace, then it had no extremal points (or faces of sufficiently low dimension). However, after transformation into slack form, it will now have faces of any dimension, and especially extremal points.
So geometrically speaking, it looks to me like the two formulations are very different. So how comes that this doesn't lead to problems?
(I know the algebraic transformation to slack form and can show that I can transform every solution of the slack form with one of the original problem and vice versa (just not one-to-one). However, this tells me very little about the geometry)

As an example take the polyhedron $P_O:=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^2\mid x_1-x_2=0\}$ with target function $f(x):=x_1-x_2$, which is to minimize.
Its slack form is
$$
P_S:=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^2\mid x_1^{\left(+\right)}-x_1^{\left(-\right)}-\left(x_2^{\left(+\right)}-x_2^{\left(-\right)}\right)=0,\quad x_1^{\left(+\right)},x_1^{\left(-\right)},x_2^{\left(+\right)},x_2^{\left(-\right)}\geq0\}
$$
The solution space of $P_O$ is the line $\{\lambda\inℝ\mid \lambda(1,-1)^T\}$, so it has no extremal point.
The solution space of $P_S$ however has $(0,0,0,0)^T$ as extremal point.
